# Can we manually move an answer up if it has higher votes?

Tags: discussion, accepted-answer

I came across a question on SQLite that has both high reviews for the question as well as the answer. Moreover, the answer with he highest rating is also marked as the right answer (rightly so):

*[How do I check in SQLite whether a table exists?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1601151/how-do-i-check-in-sqlite-whether-a-table-exists)*

Here I want to know if we can somehow move this answer up, so that it appears first when navigating for solutions in the page.

I am sorry if this is by design. I am only looking to improve my understanding of Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you click on sort by votes it will show up at the top, I think you are using oldest or active sorting on answer that's why it might not showing on top please check.

Comment: You are right. I was sorting by oldest. I had not even noticed a sorting option in the answer till you pointed it out. Thank you.

Comment: In a desktop application, Tab pages are distinctly seen because the Tab control has a strict border with the tabs having a distinction in color. I wish that in SO, the selected page had a different color and background to emphasize that it was being currently worked on.